# hook or advice when aborting org-capture before template selection?

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I'd like to be able to run some code when aborting an org-capture *before* selecting a capture template. I am able to run some code when finishing the capture process (whether completed or aborted) using defadvice. For example:

```
(defadvice org-capture-finalize
  (after delete-capture-frame activate)
  "Advise capture-finalize to close the frame"
  (if (equal "capture" (frame-parameter nil 'name))
      (delete-frame)))

(defadvice org-capture-kill
  (after delete-capture-frame activate)
  "Advise capture-kill to close the frame"
  (if (equal "capture" (frame-parameter nil 'name))
      (delete-frame)))
```

What I cannot figure out is how to run some code when I abort the capture *before* I select a template. This is when the *Org Select* buffer is prompting me to "Select a capture template". I can hit 'q' or 'C-g' to abort the capture but I cannot figure out how to hook into this. For context, what I am trying to accomplish is to be able to delete the org-capture frame when aborting. I have org-capture set to [open in a new frame](http://i-seq.com/blog/2014/05/07/org-capture-in-a-new-frame/) and I am able to delete the frame after the capture is complete or aborted *after* template selection.

Is it possible to use a hook or some advice to run some code when aborting the capture before template selection?

Comment: Just a note: `org-capture-kill` calls `org-capture-finalize`, so you don't need to advice both. Did you ever find a way to check for `q`?

Comment: Figured it out, posted as an answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to work:

```
(defadvice org-capture-select-template (around delete-capture-frame activate)
  "Advise org-capture-select-template to close the frame on abort"
  (unless (ignore-errors ad-do-it t)
    (setq ad-return-value "q"))
  (if (and
       (equal "q" ad-return-value)
       (equal "capture" (frame-parameter nil 'name)))
      (delete-frame)))
```

This checks the return value of `org-capture-select-template`, which is what `org-capture` calls to set `entry` and later call `error "Abort"` if it returns `q`, as you've seen. This advice deletes the capture frame if it does indeed return `q`.

<strike>Note that it does not handle `C-g` in template selection.</strike> Nevermind, fixed that. I set the return value to `q` on error (ie, on `C-g`), on the assumption that the resulting behaviour in `org-capture` is the same. As far as I can tell by reading the source, it is (the only difference is that `error` gets called in `org-capture` instead of `org-capture-select-template`).

Oh, and `org-capture-kill` calls `org-capture-finalize`, so you don't need to advise the former.

Comment: Excellent! I just updated my config with this and it is working great so far. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Sure:

```lisp
(defadvice org-capture-select-template
    (before org-before-capture-template activate)
  (message "bar"))
```

Or the extended version (checks for <kbd>C-g</kbd>):

```lisp
(defadvice org-capture-select-template
    (around org-around-capture-template activate)
  (message "trying")
  (if (ignore-errors ad-do-it t)
      (message "success")
    (message "fail")))
```

If you want to check for <kbd>q</kbd>, you'll have to browse org source,
find where it's bound and advice that.

Comment: Thanks this helps but doesn't quite get me there. I can run code before or after org-capture-select-template but I can't find a way to tell if the capture was aborted. Any idea?

Comment: You want to abort with q or C-g?

Comment: Right, I want to know when q or C-g was entered in the Org Select buffer so I can clean up the frame.

Comment: Thanks, based on your help, I was able to get the following to handle C-g:

`(defadvice org-capture-select-template
  (around org-around-capture-template activate)
  (unless (ignore-errors ad-do-it t)
    (if (equal "capture" (frame-parameter nil 'name))
        (delete-frame))))`

I still haven't figured out a way to handle 'q' though. It doesn't seem to be bound to a function - afaict, it just [signals an "Abort" error](http://orgmode.org/cgit.cgi/org-mode.git/tree/lisp/org-capture.el#n565). My elisp isn't strong enough to know what to do with that.